# centos:centos7 image is missing libgcc_s.so for cross compiling aarch64

Tags: gcc, dockerfile, centos7, arm64

I'm trying to setup a docker file that uses the x86_64 centos:centos7 docker image to cross compile to aarch64. The only problem is I'm missing libgcc_s.so for cross compiling, and I'm not sure why. I also noticed that there were no official glibc-aarch64 so I went with Computational's packages. I've provided my docker file, and any help would be appreciated.

```
FROM centos:centos7 
RUN yum -y update \
  && yum -y install epel-release \
  && yum -y install clang gcc gcc-c++ make wget \
  && yum -y install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu gcc-c++-aarch64-linux-gnu

RUN yum install -y http://springdale.princeton.edu/data/springdale/7/x86_64/os/Computational/glibc-aarch64-linux-gnu-2.24-2.sdl7.2.noarch.rpm
RUN yum install -y http://springdale.princeton.edu/data/springdale/7/x86_64/os/Computational/glibc-aarch64-linux-gnu-devel-2.24-2.sdl7.2.noarch.rpm
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the exact reason why, but gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu and gcc-c++-arch64-linux-gnu were compiled with --disable-shared. This prevents them from building libgcc_s.so. My best guess on why is because the shared library isn't always used and it's more common to use libgcc.a.

The two solutions that I had were to either build libgcc from source, or to copy the libgcc_s.so from another repo with the same version. I ended up extracting libgcc_s.so from  libgcc-4.8.5-44.el7.aarch64.rpm.